# show by using mathematics induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series

show by using mathematics induction?

$$
\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{2^n}{n!}\right)=0
$$

I know that we have to use squeeze theorem but I am  not really able to prove that.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $2^2$ and not $2^n$?

Comment: oh sorry its 2^n

Comment: You want to use induction? Induction is used for proving something about a well ordered set. You are not proving anything here for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: oh sorry it's  "show that" not "prove"

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can only use induction if you want to show some thing is true for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n\geqslant 3$,$$\frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac21\cdot\frac22\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac2n\leqslant2\left(\frac23\right)^{n-2}\text,$$because $\frac2n\leqslant\frac23$. Now, use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac23\right)^n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

First show by induction  (2^n)/n! <= (2)(2/3)^(n-2) for all n>=3 .You should know that the right side tends to 0 as n --> $\infty$ and the left side is non negative .

Answer (score 1):

Another way of showing that without using induction could be the following one;

Well for $n \geq 0$ we have that 
$$
0\leq \frac{2^n}{n!} \leq \frac{e^n}{n!}
$$
Taking that into account, first of all we must show the following (by using Stirling's formula);
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^n}{n!} \sim \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{2n}}{n^n\cdot \sqrt{2 \pi n}}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{e^2}{n}\right)^n\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}=0
$$
Finally, applying squeeze theorem we have;
$$
0\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2^n}{n!} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^n}{n!}
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}=0
$$